# Android Signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I read many posts here and on other sites, but can not find the problem creating my Error:
I use an AsyncTask because I want to easily manipulate the UI Thread before and after Execution.
In doInBackground I create a ThreadPoolExecutor and execute Runnables.
If I only execute 1 Runnable with the Executor, there is no Problem, but if I execute another Runnable I get following Error:

```
06-26 18:00:42.288: A/libc(25073): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7f486162 (code=1), thread 25106 (pool-1-thread-2)
06-26 18:00:42.304: D/dalvikvm(25073): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 2% free 8908K/9056K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 45ms
06-26 18:00:42.327: I/System.out(25073): In Check All with Prefix: a and Length: 4
06-26 18:00:42.390: I/DEBUG(126): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  ***
06-26 18:00:42.390: I/DEBUG(126): Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
06-26 18:00:42.390: I/DEBUG(126): Revision: '9'
06-26 18:00:42.390: I/DEBUG(126): pid: 25073, tid: 25106, name: pool-1-thread-2  >>>     de.uni_duesseldorf.cn.distributed_computing2 <<<
06-26 18:00:42.390: I/DEBUG(126): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 7f486162

...

06-26 18:00:42.538: I/DEBUG(126): memory map around fault addr 7f486162:
06-26 18:00:42.538: I/DEBUG(126):     60292000-60391000 
06-26 18:00:42.538: I/DEBUG(126):     (no map for address)
06-26 18:00:42.538: I/DEBUG(126):     bed14000-bed35000 [stack]
```

I set up the ThreadPoolExecutor like this:

```
// numberOfPackages: Number of Runnables to be executed
public void initializeThreadPoolExecutor (int numberOfPackages)
{
    int corePoolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    int maxPoolSize = numberOfPackages;
    long keepAliveTime = 60;
    final BlockingQueue workingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workingQueue);
}
```

I have no clue, why it fails when starting the second Thread.
Maybe Memory Leaks?

Any Help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you executing any native code using the NDK?

Comment: No. I am not using any native code via NDK. I just try to list all permutations from specific chars of a given length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem.

I was creating the working queue as a local variable in `initializeThreadPoolExecutor()`.
After exiting the method, it seems the working queue was deleted by the Java Garbage Collector, so it was inaccessible when I wanted to add another `Task` to the queue.

To fix the problem I created a global variable `workingQueue` and used this when initializing my `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: How did you track the problem down? I'm trying to figure out what's causing my own SIGSEGV. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but I figured out that the crash occured because I was storing Bitmaps in my objects and Android cannot handle Bitmaps well. I changed the data type from Bitmap to String by converting Bitmaps to Base64 string which solved the fatal issue. This might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not executing any native code of your own (or from a third-party library that you added), then you are tripping over some bug in your copy of Android on this device. While bugs in native code can result in a `SIGSEGV`, nothing you do from Java should.

If you can reproduce this across multiple devices/emulators from multiple manufacturers, then the problem may be in Android itself. If the problem only shows up on a single device, then it is likely to be a bug unique to that device.

Answer (score 0):

Let the `RejectionExecutionHandler` handle it,
Just add another parameter (`new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()`) to the instantiation of `ThreadPoolExecutor`  as below

```
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workingQueue,new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

Comment: Thanks. But this also did not help.